# How to parse string to date with hour in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, datetime

I've got string with date

```
var day = '2016-04-20'
```

And i want to parse it to `2016-02-01 23:59:59` because when i'll send this string as a query to database. Then is recognize as `2016-04-20 00:00:00`. 
I know that i could sent it like this:  `day+' 23:59:59'` however it looks unprofessional ;)

---

@EDIT

I think good idea would be:  `Date.parse(day) + 1` however `Date.parse` return the number of milliseconds between January 1, 1970 and the day.

Comment: Ive added the answer u can do it by format

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in mysql date format like this

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%y:%m:%d %T:%f')
```

e.g date is '2016-04-20'
 then

```
   SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2016-04-20','%y:%m:%d %T:%f')
```

Comment: u r sending this to query in database so it sholdn'nt matter to parse it in mysql

Comment: it is if i've got multiply query, i dont want to change it in every query

Comment: i thought appending the string is betther solution  then

Comment: y u cant do it by appending ? @DiPix

Comment: I can, but i thought there is better way than `day+' 23:59:59'`, you know better practice.

Comment: well it give u current time or hour but if u want 23:59:59 always then i think there is no solution other than this or mysql format

Answer (score 0):

This...

```
var day = '2016-04-20'
var mydate = new Date(day);
mydate.setMinutes(mydate.getMinutes() - 1);
var mydatestring = mydate.toISOString().slice(0, 10) + " " + mydate.toISOString().slice(11,19);
```

...however be VERY careful as JS on the clients machine can very often be different to the server time, even in the same country!  so don't expect the times to be 100% correct

**UPDATED** - first version missed the point of the question

Comment: Well kinda complicated, and result is `2016-04-19 23:59:00` instead `2016-04-20 23:59:00'` however i understand an idea. Hm... maybe appending the string isn't so bad `day+' 23:59:59'`.

Comment: well yeah, I'd just append the string, there is no real danger in terms of time zone calculations and it's much more concise readable code!